# GD2 library in PHP not installing

Tags: php, iis, gd

I'm having problems installing the GD library. I'm using an IIS server with PHP 5.2.14. I uncommented `extension=php_gd2.dll` in php.ini.

This is the error:

```
gd: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API =20060613
PHP compiled with modlule API = 20090626
These options need to match
  in Unknown on Line 0
```

I downloaded various PHP versions to try and get the correct DLL, including thread-safe 5.2.14. I would then restart my application pool and try to load a file that uses the GD library. Are there other files necessary for gd2 to work? Are there any quick ways to solve this without reinstalling PHP entirely?

Comment: Don't change your PHP version. You need to update your GD version (note that GD is saying it's using api version 2006, and your PHP is using api 2009 - that's a 3 year difference).

Comment: right when I use different versions I get different .dll errors. IE Using 5.4 i get a different error.

Comment: You have to use modules compiled against the same API version. You can't mix/match. Don't downgrade your PHP version. you'll end up with fewer built-in functions, more security holes, etc... Upgrade to a newer GD.

Comment: I've just been taking the php_gd2.dll's from their ext folders from the download

Comment: I just tried 5.3.10, which I think is the correct version but now I don't get any errors and page still doesn't display properly. I restarted the application pool, do i need to restart the webserver?

Comment: changed permissions of IUSR of the .dll that I added to read/execute... restarted server last night still no luck. Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something simple

Comment: Put a script with contents `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` under web server's root directory. Execute it in your browser. There will be a section listing loaded extensions, make sure that GD is **in** the list

Comment: GD is not in that list on the php info page. How do I get it there? I thought uncommenting it in php.ini with a correct .dll in the extension folder would be how it gets added there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, iis7 was not configured properly for php - I searched for a guide that walked me through. Second the directory was incorrect, whenever I reset the iis server it originally would say one directory when ISAPI api was being used- but after 2 mins it would say extension_dir was in another directory when cgi/fastcgi is being used. So i created that directory that it wanted (which was different than any of my php.ini's). The one it was pulling from needed to be put in the C:/windows directory, but even though I had it set to go to "./ext" it wanted to go to Program files/PHP-- extremely weird. Third, I had to add IUSR to the permissions of any folder being used.

Comment: I was having a similar issue where GD library wasn't loading at all. I installed this extension for IIS http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/releases/view/69115 which runs a recommendation list. One of the recommendations fixed my GD install. I believe it was not pointing to the /ext directory, like Jonathan mentions in this answer. That IIS extension fixed the config problems.